# Is there a way to programmatically start the Mobile me synchronization?

Tags: objective-c, osx-snow-leopard, daemon, mobileme

What I would like to create is a utility that runs the Mobile Me synchronization basing a defined schedule, and avoid it starts when Time Machine is already backing up files.

Is there a way to invoke the Mobile Me synchronization from an application, or a daemon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dotmacsyncclient` through NSTask or NSAppleScript, location:

```
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DotMacSyncManager.framework/Versions/A/Resources/
```

Usage:

```
Usage: mobilemesyncclient [options], version 446
    --sync
        Options:
        --entitynames <entities to sync>
        --dataclass <dataclass to sync>
        --username <account username>
        --password <account password>
        --pushtruth
        --pulltruth
    --dumpchangelog <changelog path>
        Options:
        --tdir <target directory>
    --dumpchanges <changelog number> --dataclass <dataclass name>
    --listdataclasses
        Required:
        --username <account username>
        --password <account password>
    --listdataclass <dataclass name>
        Required:
        --username <account username>
        --password <account password>
    --downloaddc <dataclass name> --tdir <target directory>
        Required:
        --username <account username>
        --password <account password>
    --uploaddc <dataclass name> --sdir <source directory>
        Required:
        --username <account username>
        --password <account password>
        Options:
        --clear
        --needstruth
    --removeclient <client name>
        Required:
        --username <account username>
        --password <account password>
    --listclients
        Required:
        --username <account username>
        --password <account password>
```